# Get range from sparse datetimeindex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, date-range

I have this kind of pandas DataFrame for each user in a large database.

[image]

each row is a period of length [start_date, end_date], but sometimes 2 consecutive rows are in fact the same period : `end_date` is equal to the following `start_date` (red underlining). Sometimes periods even overlap on more than 1 date.

I would like to get the "real periods" by combining rows which corresponds to the same periods.

**What I have tried**

```
def split_range(name):
    df_user = de_201512_echant[de_201512_echant.name == name]
    # -- Create a date_range with a length [min_start_date, max_start_date]
    t_date = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2005-01-01", "2015-12-12").date)
    for row in range(0, df_user.shape[0]):
        start_date = df_user.iloc[row].start_date
        end_date = df_user.iloc[row].end_date
        if ((pd.isnull(start_date) == False) and (pd.isnull(end_date) == False)):
            t = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date))
            t["period_%s" % (row)] = 1
            t_date = pd.merge(t_date, t, right_index=True, left_index=True, how="left")
        else:
            pass

    return t_date
```

which yields a DataFrame where each colunms is a period (1 if in the range, NaN if not) :

```
t_date
Out[29]: 
            period_0  period_1  period_2  period_3  period_4  period_5  \
2005-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-03       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-04       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-05       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-06       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-07       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-08       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-09       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-10       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2005-01-11       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Then if I sum all the columns (periods) I got almost exactly what I want :

```
full_spell = t_date.sum(axis=1)
full_spell.loc[full_spell == 1]

Out[31]: 
2005-11-14    1.0
2005-11-15    1.0
2005-11-16    1.0
2005-11-17    1.0
2005-11-18    1.0
2005-11-19    1.0
2005-11-20    1.0
2005-11-21    1.0
2005-11-22    1.0
2005-11-23    1.0
2005-11-24    1.0
2005-11-25    1.0
2005-11-26    1.0
2005-11-27    1.0
2005-11-28    1.0
2005-11-29    1.0
2005-11-30    1.0
2006-01-16    1.0
2006-01-17    1.0
2006-01-18    1.0
2006-01-19    1.0
2006-01-20    1.0
2006-01-21    1.0
2006-01-22    1.0
2006-01-23    1.0
2006-01-24    1.0
2006-01-25    1.0
2006-01-26    1.0
2006-01-27    1.0
2006-01-28    1.0

2015-07-06    1.0
2015-07-07    1.0
2015-07-08    1.0
2015-07-09    1.0
2015-07-10    1.0
2015-07-11    1.0
2015-07-12    1.0
2015-07-13    1.0
2015-07-14    1.0
2015-07-15    1.0
2015-07-16    1.0
2015-07-17    1.0
2015-07-18    1.0
2015-07-19    1.0
2015-08-02    1.0
2015-08-03    1.0
2015-08-04    1.0
2015-08-05    1.0
2015-08-06    1.0
2015-08-07    1.0
2015-08-08    1.0
2015-08-09    1.0
2015-08-10    1.0
2015-08-11    1.0
2015-08-12    1.0
2015-08-13    1.0
2015-08-14    1.0
2015-08-15    1.0
2015-08-16    1.0
2015-08-17    1.0
dtype: float64
```

But I could not find a way to slice all the time range of this sparse datetime index to finally get my desired output : the original dataframe containing the "real" period of time.

It might not be the most efficient way to do this, so If you have alternatives, do not hesitate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much more efficient way to do this by using `apply`:

```
 def get_range(row):
  '''returns a DataFrame containing the day-range from a "start_date"
  and a "end_date"'''
  start_date = row["start_date"]
  end_date = row["end_date"]
  period = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="1D")

  return pd.Dataframe(period, columns='days_in_period')

# -- Apply get_range() to the initial df
t_all = df.apply(get_range)
# -- Drop overlapping dates
t_all.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```